# How to prevent program from crashing with StackOverFlowException?

Tags: c#

Below is the code snippet I came across in one interview.

```
    public class ClassA
    {
        public void Method1()
        {
            ClassB c = new ClassB();
            c.Method2();
        }
    }
    public class ClassB
    {

        public void Method2()
        {
            ClassA c = new ClassA();
            c.Method1();
        }
    }
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ClassA c = new ClassA();
            c.Method1();
        }
    }
```

The question was, What would be the best way to prevent this? Program is crashing with this code as it is looping to infinite loop.

Comment: Your program is designed to have infinite loop, system have limited resources, so something will overflow at some point of time. You can not stop it unless there is a condition that allows a function to return without further calling another function before the stack is really full!!

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have method 1 call method 2 and method 2 call method 1  without some guard to tell them when to stop.  It's just like recursion without a stopping condition.

No one can guide you on what is without more details.

Comment: I agree with you. But the question is, what if two developers writes two such classes and we end up in this situation. Is there any precaution we could have taken to prevent such occurrences?
I answered same to the interviewer but he didn't seem convinced.

Comment: Code review, static analyzers, unit tests - ultimately it comes down to communication and smart developers.  A single unit test for either class would reveal it immediately, even if you used mocks. Maybe you don't want a job at a company that asks such foolish questions.

Answer (score 0):

You have circular dependency that you need to solve with design change. First step for solving circular dependency is introducing interfaces, but this will only mask possible bad design. Check these example of circular dependency: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/616344/What-is-Circular-dependency-and-how-do-we-resolve